# [wer]'d [windows-error-reporting] go?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

I wondered why I sometimes see WER questions that I didn't see before although I follow the WER tag. The reason is: some of them were not [WER](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/wer/info) questions (45), they were [Windows-Error-Reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/windows-error-reporting/info) questions (51).

You can put the tag wiki into [WinMerge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinMerge), and it says "The selected files are identical". I suggest [windows-error-reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-error-reporting) as the parent, since it is not an abbreviation and let [wer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wer) point to it.

Only a few people have enough reputation on these tags to suggest the synonym and vote for it, so maybe a moderator should just do it since it's so obvious.

Regarding the impact: nobody has a badge in these tags, and nobody will get one from the merge.

Comment: [wer]'d [windows-error-reporting] go?

Comment: [wer] doesn't seem to be used for anything else than [windows-error-reporting], but wouldn't it be quicker to do a quick retag? Also, considering that there is an overlap of 11 questions, something has to be done.

Comment: @ArtjomB.: in such a case I guess people would introduce [wer] again, because the abbreviation is common

Comment: @ThomasWeller Once a tag is synonymed to another tag, it can no longer be an independent tag again unless a moderator makes it so.

Comment: @TinyGiant: as far as I understood, ArtjomB didn't want to synonymize but burninate instead. In that case there would not have been a synonym any more

Comment: Ahh, I misunderstood.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[wer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wer) is now a syn. of and has been merged into [windows-error-reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-error-reporting)

Comment: ex. brev. conf.